# angular+express can't find the ejs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

Must have missed something, setting up a webpage which is suppose to use routing, and think I have got it working, of sorts, but for some reason the "partials" route can't find my files, but can't figure out why.

So the route for partial is set up as:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/:name', function(req, res, next) {
    var name = req.params.name;
    console.log("Was asked to send /partials/" + name);
    res.render('/partials/' + name)
});

module.exports = router;
```

I am using ejs, and it is loaded as follows in the app:

```
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

The app seems to be loading everything else OK (./ for index)). But when I make a call to my route partials (and it does seem to pick up the right one) I get

```
Was asked to send /partials/index
GET /partials/index 500 4.041 ms - 1517
GET /favicon.ico 304 3.519 ms - -
```

And the browser outputs:

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "/partials/index" in views directory "/Users/bengtbjorkberg/WebstormProjects/BabyPads-prod/views"
    at EventEmitter.app.render (/Users/bengtbjorkberg/WebstormProjects/BabyPads-prod/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:555:17)
    at ServerResponse.res.render (/Users/bengtbjorkberg/WebstormProjects/BabyPads-prod/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:938:7)
    at /Users/bengtbjorkberg/WebstormProjects/BabyPads-prod/routes/partials.js:11:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/bengtbjorkberg/WebstormProjects/BabyPads-prod/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:82:5)
    at next (/Users/bengtbjorkberg/WebstormProjects/BabyPads-prod/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:110:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/bengtbjorkberg/WebstormProjects/BabyPads-prod/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:91:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/bengtbjorkberg/WebstormProjects/BabyPads-prod/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:82:5)
    at /Users/bengtbjorkberg/WebstormProjects/BabyPads-prod/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:267:22
    at param (/Users/bengtbjorkberg/WebstormProjects/BabyPads-prod/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:340:14)
    at param (/Users/bengtbjorkberg/WebstormProjects/BabyPads-prod/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:356:14)
```

Triple checked the directories, and the files are definitely there. The thing is that the angular routing seems to ask for the right file, and if i go to 127.0.0.1:30016/partials/about I get the same error message.

Any suggestions?

Comment: try `res.render('partials/' + name)`

Comment: That made no difference what so ever, neither did adding ejs in the end. As far as I can tell, it is really that the partial route can not read the files, but doing an ls on the system, the file is definitely where the error message says it is looking.

Comment: OK, seems like that fixed the problem, but did not do it before, certain I had it set without the leading / to start with (done quite a few bits and bobs to try to get it to work correctly)